# How can I remove the icon with the Y shape?

Tags: modeling, collections

I'm so new to use blender.

I am the user of Maya before and I wanted to start to use blender.

I got some issue that I don't understand.
When I imported an object, there was hierarchy things happened in the collection.

When I dragged the object in the last child out of the hierarchy but it was linked.
When I unlinked, it is totally disappeared.

How can I deal with it? and what is the y icon's meaning

---

Thanks for the answer, but I didn't work.

To clear my question, I add images

[image]

The icon is that I circled with red.
and when I dragged out the last one named 'defaultobject.001'

[image]

'defaultobject.001' was grayed out and still exist.

When I delete the grayed one, the copied one also deleted

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Unlink* doesn't mean that you want to unparent, it means that you want to remove the object from its collection. If it's not in any other collection it will be removed for good. If you want to unparent, <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the object and drop it on the collection icon, or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> in the 3D scene.

Comment: To add to @moonboots answer, the 'y' icon in the Outliner is probably an Empty and the objects in that heirarchy are parented to it. You can see what most of the icons are by hitting Shift-A in the 3D view and looking at the icons in the Add menu.