# How to remove the icon with the Y shape?

Tags: modeling, outliner

I'm new to Blender former user of Maya.

When I imported an object, there was hierarchy things happened in the collection with Y icon.

[image]

When I dragged the object in the last child out of the hierarchy but it was grayed out.

When I unlinked, it is totally disappeared with copied one.

[image]

How can I deal with it and what is the y icon's meaning?

Comment: Do not ask the same question twice. [How can I remove the icon with the Y shape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/303052/how-can-i-remove-the-icon-with-the-y-shape) You can edit your question to provide more information to get better results.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just drag and drop, the object is not part of the collection anymore, but in your case, as it is still the children of an object that is still in the collection, it still appears greyed out.

If you unlink an object that is part of one collection only, it is definitely removed from your *Outliner*, as if you did a simple *Delete*.

If you want the object to be still part of its original collection, don’t do a simple drag and drop, do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> drag and drop onto its new collection, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works!

I have a question. Do you know is Y means and why?

Comment: the Y is the icon of the empties